# SharePoint Branding HTML Conversion

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, branding, xml

I've done branding many times before but a new issue popped up today. I use Muse to design my sites, but today when I converted the master page from html to a SharePoint master page I got a

> SharePoint requires HTML files to be XML-compliant. Your file isn't XML-compliant, likely because of tag properties without quotes, missing closing tags, or invalid properties in tags. 
>   'data-main' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 603, position 80.
>   Occurred at: 2/8/2017 2:10:12 PM
>   Run the file through an XML validator, fix any issues using your HTML editor, save the file, and refresh this preview.

When I take out the line

```
async data-main="scripts/museconfig.js?crc=168988563"
```

It shows up just fine but the java that makes the menus drop down stops working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say that properties (should say attributes) need quotes they really mean it. So even an attribute with no value needs the equals and quotes. You need to change it to

```
async="" data-main="scripts/museconfig.js?crs=168988563"
```

Comment: Or maybe async="true"

Comment: That did fix the error, but the menu still isn't working. It should drop down on click. Perhaps the two aren't related. I will check into it and if not make sure to come back mark that as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you... works for me too.